# svelte goto remain previous component

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

hi I have a categories pages with url `categories/{slug}` and a `/products` page in this 2 page I load a same component but when in `/products` page I click in a category item and goes to `categories/{slug}` I see 2 component in my page (previous component remain)

I change the url with `goto()` and I don't want to refresh the page.

I tried `{#key}` in layout but it's not working.

Comment: Hi, we experienced same issue when we were using svelte/animate. https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-animate

Answer (score 1):

> I tried `{#key}` in layout but it's not working.

This sound like the problem. When you add a component to the layout it will appear in any pages that use the layout.

Your approach is probably just off, either add the component to the two route pages or *only* the layout. Hard to tell without more code.